# How to convert ICD-9 codes into ICD-10 codes using General Equivalence Mapping (GEM)?

Tags: r, tibble, data-wrangling

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Classification_of_Diseases):

*The International Classification of Diseases (ICD) is a globally used diagnostic tool for epidemiology, health management and clinical purposes.*

For short, ICD is a list of codes which helps to describe disesases in an unambiguous way.

I want to transform a medical database using the 9th version of ICD (ICD-9) into one using the 10th vesrion (ICD-10). One can find on the Center for Disesaes Control and prevention (CDC) [website](https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/icd/icd10cm.htm) a mapping file between the two versions.

The first difficulty arises from the fact that some one ICD-9 code could be translated in more than one ICD-10 codes, which then are some kind of synoymous.

The harder issue is that, some codes must be translated into one combinaison of two or three ICD-10 codes (three is a maximum).

To describe that complexity, the mapping [file](https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Publications/ICD10CM/2018/Dxgem_2018.zip) from CDC looks like that for the code `8190`:

```
| `ICD-9` | `ICD-10`  | quality |
|---------+-----------+---------+
| "8190"  | "S4291XA" |  10111  |
| "8190"  | "S5291XA" |  10111  |
| "8190"  | "S4292XA" |  10112  |
| "8190"  | "S5292XA" |  10112  |
| "8190"  | "S4290XA" |  10121  |
| "8190"  | "S5290XA" |  10121  |
| "8190"  | "S2220XA" |  10122  |
| "8190"  | "S2249XA" |  10123  |
```

The quality column represents flags which mean:

- First digit: 1 == not an exact match
- Second digit: 1 == there is no match
- Third digit: 1 == The code must be translated by a combinaison of codes
- Fourth digit: scenario
- Fifth digit: choice list

A scenario is subdivided into two or more choice lists of codes in the target system. These are the codes that must be linked together as a unit in an applied mapping to satisfy the equivalent meaning of the combination code in the source system. A choice list contains one or more codes in the target system that express a portion of the meaning of the code in the source system. A code must be included from each choice list in a scenario to satisfy the equivalent meaning of the code in the source system.

Another important constraint I have, is that I just want to keep the four first characters of the ICD-10 codes, so I have prepared the data this way:

```
| `ICD-9` | `ICD-10`  | quality | 4-char ICD-10 | scenario | choice list |
|---------+-----------+---------+---------------+----------+-------------|
| "8190"  | "S4291XA" |  10111  |    "S429"     |    1     |      1      |
| "8190"  | "S5291XA" |  10111  |    "S529"     |    1     |      1      |
| "8190"  | "S4292XA" |  10112  |    "S429"     |    1     |      2      |
| "8190"  | "S5292XA" |  10112  |    "S529"     |    1     |      2      |
| "8190"  | "S4290XA" |  10121  |    "S429"     |    2     |      1      |
| "8190"  | "S5290XA" |  10121  |    "S529"     |    2     |      1      |
| "8190"  | "S2220XA" |  10122  |    "S222"     |    2     |      2      |
| "8190"  | "S2249XA" |  10123  |    "S224"     |    2     |      3      |
```

I also need to use tidyverse `tibble`s, because I want to use nested lists inside the output dataframe. The output dataframe should be like this:

```
|--------+-------------+----------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------|
| ICD-9  | Nb of match | One code matches     |       Two codes matches |             Three codes matches |
|--------+-------------+----------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------|
| "8190" |           6 | list("S429", "S529") | list(c("S429", "S529")) | list(c("S429", "S222", "S224"), |
|        |             |                      |                         |      c("S529", "S222", "S224")) |
|--------+-------------+----------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------|
```

We obtain two one-code-matches and only one two-code-match because when you explore the scenario where `scenario == 1` with truncated codes you obtain 4 ways of combining the choices:

```
S429 S429 => S429
S429 S529 
S529 S429 (identical as the one above)
S529 S529 => S529
```

---

So here is a dataset of input:

```
library(tibble)
input <- structure(list(`ICD-9` = c("00320", "00589", "00589", "01480","01480", "8190", "8190", "8190", "8190", "8190", "8190", "8190", "8190", "36570"), `ICD-10` = c("A0220", "A054", "A058", "A1832", "A1839", "S4291XA", "S5291XA", "S4292XA", "S5292XA", "S4290XA", "S5290XA", "S2220XA", "S2249XA", "NoDx"), quality = c("00000", "10000", "10000", "10000", "10000", "10111", "10111", "10112", "10112", "10121", "10121", "10122", "10123", "11000")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",     "collector")), X2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), X3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector")), skip = 0), class = "col_spec"))
```

which looks like:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 3
   `ICD-9` `ICD-10` quality
   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>  
 1 00320   A0220    00000  
 2 00589   A054     10000  
 3 00589   A058     10000  
 4 01480   A1832    10000  
 5 01480   A1839    10000  
 6 8190    S4291XA  10111  
 7 8190    S5291XA  10111  
 8 8190    S4292XA  10112  
 9 8190    S5292XA  10112  
10 8190    S4290XA  10121  
11 8190    S5290XA  10121  
12 8190    S2220XA  10122  
13 8190    S2249XA  10123  
14 36570   NoDx     11000
```

And the expected output:

```
output <- tibble(`ICD-9` = c("00320", "00589", "01480", "8190", "36570"), `Nb of match` = c(1, 2, 1, 5, 0), `One code matches` = list(list("A0220"), list("A054", "A058"),  list("A183"), list("S429", "S529"), NA), `Two codes matches` = list(NA, NA, NA, list(c("S429", "S529")), NA), `Three codes matches` = list(NA, NA, NA, list(c("S429", "S222", "S224"), c("S529", "S222", "S224")), NA))
```

which looks like that:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

My approach here is to group by ICD-9 and scenario to get the initial two and three-code matches.  Then condense these so there is one row for each ICD-9 code.  Then account for all the possible duplication and the movement from one column to another based on that duplication.  Then add up the number of matches.
I wrote a lot of short custom functions to account for NA's and character(0)'s etc.
This gives the result you requested, but this was a pretty small data sample for how complicated this question is.  I tried to make it work generally, but it might not.

```
library(dplyr)
working <- input %>% 
  mutate(`4-char ICD-10` = substr(`ICD-10`, 1, 4), 
         scenario = substr(quality, 4, 4), 
         `choice list` = substr(quality, 5, 5))

expand_across <- function(...) {
  do.call(tidyr::expand_grid, list(..., .name_repair = "universal")) %>% 
    suppressMessages() %>% 
    setNames(NULL) %>% 
    as.matrix() %>% 
    apply(1, list) %>% 
    unlist(recursive = FALSE)
}

first_not_na <- function(x) {
  for (i in seq_along(x)){
    if (!is.na(x[i])) return(x[i])
  }
  return(x[1])
}

fix_groups <- function(x) {
  lapply(x, \(y) {
    ans <- unique(lapply(y, \(z) sort(unique(z), na.last = TRUE)))
    if (identical(ans, list(NA_character_))) ans <- unlist(ans)
    ans
  })
}

pick_len <- function(x, len) {
  ans <- x[sapply(x, length) == len]
  ans[identical(ans, character(0))] <- NA_character_
  ans
}

list_len <- function(x) {
  if_else(!is.list(x), 0L, length(x))
}

by_scen <- working %>% 
  group_by(`ICD-9`, scenario) %>% 
  summarize(`Nb of match` = 0L, 
            `One code matches` = recode(first(substr(quality, 1, 3)), 
                                        `000` = list(as.list(`4-char ICD-10`)), 
                                        `100` = list(as.list(unique(`4-char ICD-10`))), 
                                        .default = list(NA_character_)),
         `Two code matches` = recode(first(substr(quality, 3, 3)), 
                                     `1` = if (last(`choice list`) == "2") 
                                       list(expand_across(
                                         `4-char ICD-10`[`choice list` == "1"],
                                         `4-char ICD-10`[`choice list` == "2"])) else 
                                           list(NA_character_),
                                     .default = list(NA_character_)),
         `Three code matches` = recode(first(substr(quality, 3, 3)), 
                                       `1` = if (last(`choice list`) == "3") 
                                         list(expand_across(`4-char ICD-10`[`choice list` == "1"],
                                                          `4-char ICD-10`[`choice list` == "2"],
                                                          `4-char ICD-10`[`choice list` == "3"])) else 
                                                            list(NA_character_),
                                       .default = list(NA_character_)), 
         .groups = 'drop')
output <- by_scen %>% 
  group_by(`ICD-9`) %>% 
  summarize(across(!scenario, first_not_na), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  mutate(`Two code matches` = fix_groups(`Two code matches`)) %>% 
  mutate(`Three code matches` = fix_groups(`Three code matches`)) %>% 
  mutate(`One code matches` = coalesce(`One code matches`, lapply(`Two code matches`, pick_len, len = 1))) %>% 
  mutate(`Two code matches` = lapply(`Two code matches`, pick_len, len = 2)) %>% 
  mutate(`One code matches` = coalesce(`One code matches`, lapply(`Three code matches`, pick_len, len = 1))) %>% 
  mutate(`Two code matches` = coalesce(`Two code matches`, lapply(`Three code matches`, pick_len, len = 2))) %>% 
  mutate(`Three code matches` = lapply(`Three code matches`, pick_len, len = 3)) %>% 
  mutate(`Nb of match` = sapply(`One code matches`, list_len) + 
           sapply(`Two code matches`, list_len) + 
           sapply(`Three code matches`, list_len))
```

View(output)
[image]

Comment: Great work. The `expand_across` is very neat. If you need more data I gave the link to the complete mapping file.